# Zxing CaptureActivity.handleDecode()

Tags: android, zxing

I am new to use Zxing ,When I click a button I want to scan a Two-dimensional code image .This is my MainActivity.java

```
    private Button scan;
   scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
   scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,CaptureActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SCAN_CODE);  

    }
    });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        switch (requestCode) {
        case SCAN_CODE:
             Intent myIntent=getIntent();
             Bundle bundle=myIntent.getExtras();
             QR=bundle.getString("QR");
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

it will call CaptureActivity.handleDecode(),and This is CaptureActivity.java

```
      public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode, float scaleFactor) {
            //I want to get the text in the image.
              String result = rawResult.getText(); 
              Intent intent = new Intent();  
              intent.putExtra("QR", result);  
              if(result!=null && !"".equals(result))
              setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
              else{
                  setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
              }
              finish();
}
```

But it has exception
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xrp9.png)

and I don't konw why?

Comment: Please provide a complete example. Rather than writing "This is CaptureActivity.java", **show it in your code** with `public class CaptureActivity ...`. Similarly, your first code snippet should be valid Java, meaning it should be inside a class.

Comment: Also, please copy and paste the exception here.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, this problem has been resolved, next time I will do as you say.Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `data.getStringExtra("QR")` in your case, rather than

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = myIntent.getExtras();
QR = bundle.getString("QR");
```

where `data` is `onActivityResult()`'s parameter.

And use `!result.isEmpty()` instead of `!"".equals(result)`.

It's more readable.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much.It has been resolved  by your method